# GLMNET small deviance explained; reuse of selected predictors in other model

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, glmnet, deviance

I am trying to run glmnet for logistic regression (I have some continuos predictors which I have scaled with scale() and some categorical which I turned to dummy predictors, 27 predictors, 800 observations). I passed the data to: `glmnet(x,y, family='binomial', alpha = 1, standardize = FALSE)`

The primary goal was to use LASSO method for selecting predictors, but the explained deviance by the model was only about 8.3% (everywhere I saw at least 60%). Should I stop here and give it up, or should I proceed to `cv.glmnet` and choose the model according to `cv$lambda.min` / `cv$lambda.1se` ?

After the selection I was wondering if passing selected variable to GLM and compute ods ratios would be possible / fair ?

Thank you,
Matyas

*(my first post here - please be patient with me)*

Answer (score 1):

I think in general nothing speaks against using a 2-stage procedure consisting of selecting a subset of predictors using the lasso and then using that subset for unregularized regression.

The procedure is known as the [Relaxed Lasso](http://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/relaxo.pdf) and apparently has quite nice properties (see paper).

Answer (score 0):

Is that mean the size of input x is 800*27 ? p = 27 (predictors),n = 800(observations),

not satisfied with the condition of lasso problem(n << p)?
  I'm new in `glmnet`,too.

Anyway,you can try following code to choose lambda.min and check if the corresponding dev.ratio is more than 60%

```
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x,y, family='binomial', standardize = FALSE)
ind.lambda <- which(cv.fit$lambda == cv.fit$lambda.min)
cv.fit$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio[ind.lambda]
```

Hopes help!